# Let div on the leftside take up all the space

Tags: html, css, flexbox

When having 2 divs, one on the left and one on the right.
Is it possible to have the right div aligned all the way right with a fixed width and have the left div take up all the space left?

I don't want to work with inline-

[image]

Comment: You just need to set `flex: 1` on left div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of ways to achieve this, but you may want to use flex-boxes as it's widely used these days.

Check [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=flex) to see if it meets your browser requirements.

Markup:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-container">Autofill remaining width</div>
    <div class="fixed-container">200px</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
  display: flex;
}
.left-container {
  background-color: red;
  flex: 1;
}
.fixed-container {
  flex-basis: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/fhuqm290/)

Comment: flex isn't supported on versions of ie below 11 so its not the most versatile solution https://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Comment: ie10 and below are not supported by microsoft so I don't see that as much of a problem - flex is supported by all latest browsers that are supported by their companies

Comment: @RyanEarnshaw Vendor prefix(-ms-) can be used to support IE10. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh673531(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Addressing to both last comments go to this link: https://caniuse.com/#search=flex and read the "notes" and "known issues" section. You'll find that flex, although works, works only partially because it is unsupported

Comment: @RyanEarnshaw It works only partially in IE _due to large amount of bugs present_, which is _very_ different from "unsupported". And IE10 support the older version, which in solving this case, has no bugs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS `calc() function` here to minus the `width` of fixed `.right` div from `.left` div.

> The calc() CSS function lets you perform calculations when specifying
>   CSS property values.

```css
#bx{
  background:black;
  height:200px;
  padding:10px;
}
#bx > .left{
  display:inline-block;
  width:calc(99% - 200px); /*Minus width of .right using calc()*/
  height:100%;
  background:yellow;
}
#bx > .right{
  display:inline-block;
  width:200px;
  height:100%;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="bx">
  <div class="left">Left Div</div>
  <div class="right">Right Div Fixed Width.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @S. Robijns Try scaling above code. The right div stays fixed.

Comment: That's pretty awesome, did not know about that, thanks!

Comment: Welcome @S.Robijns :-)

Comment: Why use `width: auto;`, it is the default.

Comment: @LGSon I will update that.

Answer (score 0):

I think this accomplishes what you are after but I'm not sure its the best way...

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}

.sidebar {
  float: right;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.content {
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  margin-right: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">width: 200px</div>
<div class="content">
</div>
```

Comment: this indeed seems to work, but quite a lot of code and a strange setup since the content div element comes behind the sidebar div in html

Comment: First, you don't need `width: auto;`, it is the default, second, of you use a _clearfix_ element, it should be positioned _after_ the floated element to have an effect.

Comment: okay changed my answer